# GoError: Error: could not decrypt key with given password at web3.js:6347:37(47)

Tags: go, command-prompt, ethereum, go-ethereum, geth

Purpose: I would like to unlock the Coinbase account so it can be used to transfer ethers to Metamask.

I input the following command on Windows' Command Prompt:

```
geth --datadir ~/eth-dev/ --networkid 326584 --verbosity 4 --ipcdisable --port 30301 --nodiscover -- console 2>> ~/eth-dev/eth.log
```

I could get into the Geth Javascript console. But once I typed in the command:

```
personal.unlockAccount(eth.coinbase, "123456789")
```

it returned:

GoError: Error: could not decrypt key with given password at web3.js:6347:37(47)
at native
at :1:38(5)

My passphrase is 123456789.

I also tried creating a new personal account and input a new passphrase and tried entering the two commands above
and I still got the error (in red) as stated above.

How are we supposed to fix the above error (in red)? What is the solution?
Could you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

The required syntax for unlockAccount() function is

> personal.unlockAccount(address, password, duration)

Note : Here duration is optional. This function asks for account password and **NOT** the passphrase.

**Solution to you query:**

Enter the following command by entering a blank passphrase.

> personal.unlockAccount(eth.coinbase)

If the console prompts to create/enter your password, skip it by hitting enter key.